# Insect ID, found in shower, northeast USA

Tags: species-identification

[image]

I want to know if this is the kind of critter that will lay eggs in the drain and then have larvae emerge from there. We had that a few years ago and it was nasty...

Answer (score 1):

That is a silverfish (Order, Zygentoma). The most common species of household silverfish is *Lepisma saccharina*. Details can be found here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish
They are relatively harmless.